# Trying to import docx in Python

Tags: ms-word, installation, python-3.x, pip, docx

*Fair Warning: I am extremely new to python, so please excuse any dumb mistakes I make =)*

I would like to be able to open/close/manipulate/read Word documents (docx files) on my Mac using Python. The python-docx module looked really useful, so I have been trying to install it on my system, to no avail.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Checked that I do indeed have python installed using the `python --version` command in terminal. I have version 3.7.0, so all good there.
- Checked that I do indeed have pip installed - I was able to use `pip install` and `pip uninstall` commands, so all good. I also upgraded my pip version using `pip install --upgrade pip` to `pip-19.1.1`
- Following the online documentation ([see here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html#install)), I tried `pip install python-docx`. This seemed to work just fine, and after the progress bar loaded all the way I saw:

  `Successfully built python-docx
  twisted 18.7.0 requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: python-docx
  Successfully installed python-docx-0.8.10`

  I wasn't completely sure what pyhamcrest was, but I installed it anyway just to be safe using `pip install pyhamcrest`
- As other sites suggested, I also tried to install Pillow, lxml, and python-dateutil using their respective install commands, and in each case saw the `Requirement already satisfied:` message, with an anaconda path listed.

Frustrated, I also tried `easy_install python-docx`, the manual version, and even `pip install docx` . In all cases, when I run IDLE and type `from docx import Document` or just `import docx`, I get the following message in the shell:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/Users/[my_name]/Desktop/Medical.py", line 3, in <module> `
`import docx`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'`
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Mac OsX and its Python (you mentioned Anaconda), but this should work: open a terminal, and run `pip list`, it will show you all the packages installed. Check for 'docx'. If not listed, then maybe you have 2 python installed...

Comment: @AndrewQ Thanks for the advice - didn't know about the `pip list` command. I tried it and found that `docx  0.2.4` and `python-docx  0.8.10 ` were listed, as well as `Pillow 5.2.0`and `lxml 4.3.4` and `python-dateuti 2.7.3`. It seems like everything's installed - this is so frustrating  

Comment: @victor_von_doom In the same terminal, run 'python'. You should enter in a python prompt. Try to import from there. If successful, the problem is in IDLE.

Comment: @AndrewQ Tried it in terminal - didn't work, but I did get a brand new error (yay?) `>>> from docx import Document
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docx.py", line 30, in <module>
    from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'`

Comment: I think you mixed something. I think that OsX comes with python 2.7, and you installed Anaconda with python 3.7. Use the `conda install` command to add packages to anaconda.

Comment: @AndrewQ PROGRESS!!! I ran `conda install -c conda-forge python-docx` and it downloaded a ton of modules, including python-docx! Now, I am able to do `import docx` and `from docx import Document`, but ONLY in Terminal. If I try in IDLE, I get the same errors of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'`. I am very new to Python - is there any way to get this in IDLE? Could I write a Python program directly in terminal? In Anaconda perhaps? Thank you again!

Comment: Do you run idle or idle3? Conda uses idle3. For writing programs, there is a nice IDE called [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

Comment: Run `anaconda-navigator` to explore documentation and available packages.

Comment: Update - I finally got everything working, and I'd really like to upvote your comments, @AndrewQ. I'm new to stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to let me upvote comments - could you maybe reply with like a blank answer or like copy paste your comments so I can upvote them? Either way, thanks so much!!

Comment: @victor_von_doom I've wrote an answer. Read it, and if you think it's ok, please mark it with the green tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Anaconda Python distribution has its own system of installation of packages.
After the installation of Anaconda, the variable $PATH has been modified so that anaconda python was the first, and OsX's python in the last position.
If you type "`python`" in a shell will execute the anaconda python, instead of the standard OsX python (which is 2.7, not 3.x).
Following the instructions of the package python-docx, you have installed it using `pip`, which is the default method for installing packages, but this method is not valid for Anaconda Python. So, you finished installing python-docx for the python 2.7 of OsX.
To install packages for anaconda, you must run the command
`conda install <package>`
The python-docx module for anaconda can be found in a separated repository called `conda-forge`; typing the command

`conda install -c conda-forge python-docx`

you will install the package and the requested dependencies.

Other useful commands are:
`anaconda-navigator` for exploring the Anaconda system

`anaconda-project` for managing projects with anaconda

`idle3` for Anaconda Python shell.

Before start coding, run `anaconda-navigator` and take a look at the 'Learning' section.

For a better experience, I suggest [PyCharm IDE for Anaconda](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/promo/anaconda/) from JetBrains.