# Why am I getting a ModuleNotFoundError trying to import python-docx using anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-docx

I wrote a small script that exports a formatted table, and I'd like to be able to export it to a word document. python-docx seems like the perfect solution, but it throws a ModuleNotFoundError even after an apparently successful install. I use anaconda, so I installed using `conda install python-docx conda-forge` instead of using pip as instructed [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-docx-feedstock). I also made sure conda-forge was added to the list of channels as per these instructions. Using `conda config --show` lists conda-forge next to the default channel, so I assume this was successful. Using `conda list` also shows python-docx with the installed packages on channel conda-forge. When I try to import it into my script, however, I still get an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'docx'`. I've tried using `import python-docx as docx`, `import docx as docx`, and just `import docx`, but I get the same error every time.

I found some other StackOverflow users with similar issues, but in these cases they either [used pip install instead of conda install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994568/trying-to-import-docx-in-python) or [tried to install using the default channel instead of conda-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231648/why-python-docx-is-not-found-in). There unfortunately isn't much in the way of documentation on using python-docx with anaconda as far as I'm aware; I didn't really find anything useful outside of StackOverflow.

I appreciate any help on this! I'm relatively new to coding and very new to anaconda, so I don't really know where to go from here. Thanks in advance!

Here's the full error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "protein-parser.py", line 5, in <module>
>       import docx as docx 
> , ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'docx'
```

Comment: Not a solution, but typically you would either `import docx` or `from docx import Document` (generally the latter). `import docx as docx` _should_ be equivalent to `import docx` but the former is redundant and tests providence at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `conda install -c conda-forge python-docx`.

If that doesn't work you can try 3 other alternatives here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-docx